# Excel macro / VBA: How to export a range of rows to a PDF

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, pdf

I have an Excel worksheet that contains customer requests. I'd like to export a list of each customer's requests to different PDF sheets. For example, Column A has the customers name (CustA, CustB, CustC, CustA, etc.) which isn't unique since a given customer can have more than 1 request.

I want to take all the rows with "CustA" and export that to a PDF, then take all rows with CustB and export to another PDF, etc.

I'm 90% done. The following code works... except that the generated PDF has 1 row per PAGE. I would like for all rows (all the requests of CustA, for example) to be on a single page (or multiple pages if there are many request, but not one line per page).

The problem either lies with the way I use the Union method, or with the ExportAsFixedFormat function.

Here is the code:

```
Sub ExportToPDF()

    'Declare variables
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim dict As Object
    
    'Set the worksheet you want to search
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Requests")
    
    'Set the range you want to search
    Set rng = ws.Range("A6:I30")
    
    'Create a dictionary object to store the values of column A and their corresponding rows
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    
    'Loop through each cell in the range
        For Each cell In rng.Columns(2).Cells
        
        'Check if the cell value is not empty
        If cell.Value <> "" Then
            'If the cell value is not empty, add it to the dictionary
            If dict.Exists(cell.Value) Then
                'If the value already exists in the dictionary, append the row number to the existing array
                dict(cell.Value) = dict(cell.Value) & "," & cell.Row
            Else
                'If the value does not exist in the dictionary, create a new array with the row number
                dict.Add cell.Value, cell.Row
            End If
        End If
    Next
    
    'Loop through each key in the dictionary
        For Each Key In dict.Keys
        
        'Split the array of row numbers into a range
        Dim rows As Range
        Dim ListRows As Variant
        Dim count As Integer
        count = 1
        
        ListRows = Split(dict(Key), ",")
        
        For Each num In ListRows
            If count = 1 Then
                Set rows = ws.rows(num)
                count = count + 1
            Else
                Set rows = Union(rows, ws.rows(num))
            End If
            
        Next
                        
        'Export the rows to a PDF file
        rows.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:="C:\temp\" & Key & ".pdf", Quality:=xlQualityStandard
    Next

End Sub
```

This macro will search through the range A6:I30 on the worksheet named "Feuille de temps" and will create a dictionary object with all the different values of column B as the keys and the corresponding rows as the values. It will then loop through each key in the dictionary and export the rows to a separate PDF file, naming each file according to the value of the key. The PDF files will be saved in the "C:\temp" folder.